# Text encoding issue in Java Android app

Tags: java, android, encoding, character-encoding

I'm requesting some content from my website (in my Android app) using the following code:

```
response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);


// Pull content stream from response
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
InputStreamReader rd = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
//ByteArrayOutputStream content = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
int n = 0;
char[] buffer = new char[40000];
while (n >= 0)
{
        n = rd.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        if (n > 0)
        {
            content.append(buffer, 0, n);
        }
}
ret = content.toString();
```

The content of the site is in encoded in the `Windows-1251` encoding, but in the app I get a bunch of unreadable symbols, like so:

[image]

Also, the following code snippet doesn't seem to be working either:

```
text = new String(matcher.group(1).getBytes("Windows-1251"), "UTF-8");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ,

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in_stream), "UTF-8");
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    try
    {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            content.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally 
    {
        try 
        {
            in_stream.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    ret = content.toString();
```

Comment: new InputStreamReader(in_stream, "UTF-8"), not new BufferedReader(rd, "UTF-8").